# How to iterate through the list of maps in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I can't understand how to iterate with index in Elixir.

For example, I have this snippet from java and I want to translate it into Elixir:

```
for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
   list.order = i;
}
```

Lets say that `list` is a list of maps from Elixir.
I can't understand how to do this either in Elixir way or just iterate with some index variable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the answer by Justin is perfectly valid, the idiomatic Elixir solution would be to use [`Enum.with_index/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/2):

```rb
list = ~w|a b c d e|
list
|> Enum.with_index()
|> Enum.each(fn {e, idx} -> IO.puts "Elem: #{e}, Idx: #{idx}" end)

#⇒ Elem: a, Idx: 0
#⇒ Elem: b, Idx: 1
#⇒ Elem: c, Idx: 2
#⇒ Elem: d, Idx: 3
#⇒ Elem: e, Idx: 4
```

Comment: I think both solutions are great but this one seems to be easier for me to understand.

Comment: Would `Enum.with_index` allow a value on the `Map` to be updated though (which is what I thought the OP wanted rather than just a way to simply iterate)?

Comment: @JustinNiessner `Enum.with_index` does not _allow_ or _disallow_ anything, it passes the element through, appending an index and returning a tuple. If the input is `map` to be updated, one should use `Enum.map` or `Enum.reduce` instead of `Enum.each` in the last pipeline row. There is _no_ such a thing as “map update” in Elixir. The result is nevertheless the new map.

Comment: I'm sorry I explained question not so clear. My end point was to update a list of ecto schema elements. I wanted to reassign :order key to make this list of schemas ordered. And I did it like this:

`Repo.all(query)
    |> Enum.with_index(1)
    |> Enum.each(fn {l, idx} -> update_lesson(l, %{order: idx}) end)`
`update_lesson` is just Repo.update() with changeset.

Comment: `Enum.with_index/2` now supports functions as of this PR#10552 meaning you can do something like this: `Enum.with_index(list, fn e, idx -> IO.puts "Elem: #{e}, Idx: #{idx}" end)`

Answer (score 3):

When working with a language that doesn't allow mutation of data, it's not so straightforward as iterating over a collection and setting values. Instead, you need to create a new collection with new objects that have your field set.

In Elixir, you can do this with a `foldl`:

```
List.foldl(
  list, 
  (1, map), 
  fn(l, (i, map)) -> (i+1, Map.update(map, :some_key, $(i)))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a `for` comprehension

`[debug] localized_titles %{attributes: [%{"en" => "The English Title of a Playlist"}, %{"fr" => "Le French Title of a Playlist"}]}`

```
      maps =
        for title <- localized_titles,
            _ = Logger.debug("title #{inspect(%{attributes: title})}"),
            {k, v} <- title do
          IO.puts "#{k} --> #{v}"

          Repo.insert(%PlaylistTitle{language_id: k, localizedname: v, uuid: Ecto.UUID.generate(), playlist_id: playlist.id})
        end
      Logger.debug("maps #{inspect(%{attributes: maps})}")
      {:ok, maps}
```